# MySQL Multiple JOIN with most resent timestamp from one

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have problem that I hope someone can help me with.

```
SELECT a.country_name, s.state_name, c.city_id,
LEAST (c.next_1, c.next_2, c.next_3) AS next_visit,
MAX(v.visit_time) AS last_visit
FROM city c
INNER JOIN country a ON a.id = c.country
INNER JOIN state s ON s.id = c.state 
INNER JOIN visit_log v ON CONCAT(c.country, c.state, c.city_id) = CONCAT(v.country, v.state, v.city_id)
GROUP BY CONCAT(v.country, v.state, v.city_id)
ORDER BY a.id ASC, s.id ASC, c.city_id
```

My main problem now is that I can't get the col_1 and col_2 from the visit_log corresponding with MAX(visit_log)

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c220a/2/0)

Comment: I thin k there must be a country refering column in your state table.

Comment: Is there a better way to structor this?

Comment: Yes. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (x1, x2, etc. - above, say, 2) then you're probably doing something wrong, which is why I say see normalisation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the "latest" requirement to the `join` condition:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    city c
JOIN    country a
ON      a.id = c.country
JOIN    state s
ON      s.id = c.state 
JOIN    visit_log v 
ON      v.country = c.country
        AND v.state = c.state
        AND v.city_id = c.city_id
        AND visit_time =
        (
        SELECT  MAX(visit_time)
        FROM    visit_log v2
        WHERE   v2.country = c.country
                AND v2.state = c.state
                AND v2.city_id = c.city_id
        )
```

You can find many other approaches in the [greatest-n-per-group+mysql](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group%2bmysql) tag.  For optimal speed you'd use an approach using variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT C.NAME, S.NAME, CN.ID, NV.Next_visit_1, VL.visited
FROM COUNTRY C INNER JOIN next_visit NV ON C.ID = NV.Country
INNER JOIN STATE S ON NV.State = S.ID
JOIN CITY
INNER JOIN visitor_log  VL ON CONCAT(NV.country, NV.state, NV.city) = CONCAT(VL.country, VL.state, VL.city)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I be sure that the newest date from the visitet log will be used?
And the next visit is the lowest date of the tree?

Comment: Error accepted. You can use Max and Min function for the same and then use group by clause.